# Flutter : starting the app with welcome page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and in my new project I've created a welcome screen that have 2 buttons either login or sign up , I'm using a Wrapper for the authentication and a toggle to navigate between login and sign up ... every thing works fine , but once the app lunches it shows the login screen not the welcome screen !

here is my wrapper class

```
class wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel?>(context);

    // either home or login page
    if(userModel == null){
      return const Authenticate();
    }else{
      return const Home();
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my main

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<UserModel?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: Authentication().onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Auth',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.nunitoTextTheme(),
          ),
          home: wrapper(),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

the authenticate class :

```
class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  const Authenticate({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  bool showSignIn = true ;
  void toggleView() {
    setState(() {
      showSignIn = !showSignIn;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(showSignIn){
      return LoginScreen(toggleView : toggleView);
    }else{
      return SignUpScreen(toggleView : toggleView);
    }

  }
}
```

welcome screen :

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

Body :

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      height: size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Color(0xFFA9D7CC),
      child:Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: size.width,height: 70),
          SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/images/recycle.svg" ,
              width:441.4,
              height: 294 ,
          ),
          const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 7, 0),
            child:
            Text("lets make saving the planet easy !",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 48 ,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white
              ),
            ),
          ),

           const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(27, 10, 110, 0),
            child:
            Text("start recycling and earn some money ",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20 ,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Colors.white
              ),
            ),
          ),

      SizedBox(width: size.width,height: 70),

      // login button
      SizedBox(
        width: 297,
        height: 71,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style:ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: kPrimaryPopColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)
            )
          ) ,
            onPressed: (){},
            child: const Text("login",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
              ),)),
      ),

          //sign up button
          SizedBox(
            height: 70,
            child: TextButton(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('sign up',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),),
            ),
          )

        ],
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in not full. Try to debug
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/debugger
It seems to me, that here is true

if(userModel == null){
return const Authenticate();

Comment: here is the full code on GitHub if you can help https://github.com/shahad-jeza/green_app

Comment: In main on line 24 put breakpoint and start debug